# D3 Hierarchy Links Don't Use Accessor Function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have similar code to

[D3.js Collapsible Force Layout: Links are not being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535714/d3-js-collapsible-force-layout-links-are-not-being-generated/15538261#15538261)

and I need to be able to use Hierarchy.links with an accessor function for the children of my data. IE.

```
links = d3.layout.tree()
          .children(function(d) { return d.children() })
          .links(nodes)
```

I have to use this accessor function because i'm dynamically getting the children in the function children().

Should I simply monkey patch d3 and change the d3_layout_hierarchyLinks(nodes); function to use an accessor?

?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a different method of calcuating the links.  Given by [mbostock on github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1570)

Calculate links by hand:

```
function computeLinks(nodes) {
  return d3.merge(nodes.map(function(parent) {
    return parent.computeChildren().map(function(child) {
      return {source: parent, target: child};
    });
  }));
}
```